# Can I get notified when the grpc client disconnects?

Tags: node.js, grpc

I need to catch in the server whenever a client isn't listen to the stream anymore. I thought this would do:

```
function getEvents(call) {
  const { type } = call.request
  EVENTS
    .filter((e) => e.type === type)
    .foreach((event) => call.write(event))

  call.on('end', () => { console.log('client left...') })
}
```

What I intended is that a client would connect, specify an event type, and receive a stream of events. The connection would then hang until `Ctrl+C` and "client left..." would be logged to the console.

Client code would be like:

```
function main() {
  const client = 
    new EventStore('localhost:50051', grpc.credentials.createInsecure())

  const call = client.getEvents({ type: 'Done' })
  call.on('data', (event) => console.log(event))
}
```

Everything work as expected, only the callback for `call.on('end')` never fires. I got the basics for this from the [gRPC Tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/node.html) but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A client abruptly disconnecting, without properly communicating that to the server, should eventually trigger a "cancelled" event on the server. That is what you should listen for. I would also recommend having some way of stopping your write stream when this happens.

The method you have looks like a unary request/streaming response method. This means that on the server side, you have a Writable stream, and Writable streams do not have "end" events. That is an event on a Readable stream, to indicate that you are done reading.